# Order Id not searching usaepay sandbox search functionality

Tags: magento-1.9, usaepay

I am integrating usaepay with my magento store, order is placed using usaepay in sandbox mode. But it is not searching in sandbox search feature of usaepay.

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm if there is any USAepay success page in the extension. There may have chances that your card details was not verified and your magneto could not understand the error hence by passed the response and order was placed.